# How to display data from redux store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have created action and reducer for saving messages (array) in redux store. I have created actions and reducer for it but how can I display data once it is stored in redux store ?

reducer.js:

```
import { SAVE_ITEMS, SAVE_MESSAGES} from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
    messages: [],
    items: []
}

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SAVE_MESSAGES:
            return {
                ...state,
                messages: action.payload
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

action.js:

```
import { SAVE_MESSAGES } from './types';

export const saveMessages = (messages) => ({
    type: SAVE_MESSAGES,
    payload: { messages }
})
```

In component I am saving data like this:

```
this.props.saveMessages(data)
```

and also the connect:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    author: state.chat.author,
    messages: state.chat.messages,
    message: state.chat.message
})

export default connect (mapStateToProps, { saveAuthor, saveMessages, deleteAuthor, deleteMessage })(Chat);
```

In combineReducer i.e index.js:

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import users from './loginReducer'
import allusers from './userReducer'
import chatReducer from './chatReducer'

export default combineReducers({
    users: users,
    allusers: allusers,
    chat: chatReducer
})
```

Now if I do `console.log(this.props)` see screenshot below:

[image]

Now if I do `console.log(this.props.messages)` see screenshot below:

[image]

Now I want to map over messages data and display it but I am getting error if I do `this.props.messages.messages[0]` -> error `this.props.messages[0]` gives undefined.

Screenshot: (redux tools)

[image]

Comment: are you defining a `stateToProps` mapping in your call to `connect()` ? if so, how is this defined?

Comment: @DacreDenny Edited the question please see

Comment: thanks - also, are you combining your reducers? if so, how and what is the structure of your root state (ie in relation to the chat data)

Comment: @DacreDenny updated the code

Comment: I recommend you to install the redux extension for development and see exactly how your store structure looks like: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd

Comment: @V.Sambor I have installed it but couldn't understand why is it not working

Comment: @funjoker can you also include the render code thats causing the error?

Comment: You have to add it in your store configuration it is a package called `redux-devtools-extension` and it acts as a middleware.

Comment: @V.Sambor see screenshot I have added

Comment: @DacreDenny `this.props.messages.messages` gives undefined in console and this.props.messages[0] gives error if I do console log both statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think first you can check if `this.props.messages.messages` is not undefined and then you can use `map()` to print messages like this:

```
{this.props.messages && this.props.messages.messages && this.props.messages.messages.map(function(msg,i) {
    return (
        <p>{msg.message}</p>
    )
})}
```

Comment: I am getting `TypeError: this.props.messages.map is not a function`. I think I have not created reducer and action properly that's why it is confusing to extract data. Any thing wrong in my question ?

Comment: @Triyugi Check the provided structure again, you are trying to loop over messages but he has messages.messages. And he already showed that this.props.messages is accessible.

Comment: @V.Sambor How can I modify my reducer, action and combineReducer so that the structure becomes correct ?

Comment: @V.Sambor Yes, I have missed that. Now I have corrected.

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani Yes it is working fine :) thanks. Upvoted you :) If possible can you also add the modifications I need to make in my reducer and action so that I get messsages and not messages.messages ? I also want to ask what is wrong in my code structure why is it displaying messages.messages in console ?

Comment: @funjoker Thanks. I think structure is perfectly fine. No need to re-structure.